# how to do multiple target linear regression in Spark MLLib?

Tags: apache-spark

Spark ML LinearRegression seems to regress against a single label.

```
LabeledPoint(label: Double, features: Array[Double])

https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/api/mllib/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/LabeledPoint.html
```

However, with my problem, I need to predict a vector

e.g.

```
LabeledPoint(label: Array[Double], features: Array[Double])
```

Is there a way for me to do this? (this is supported in sickit-learn and I am trying to do it in spark)

ps 1: If this is not possible in MLLib directly, is there a tutorial on how to implement this from scratch using spark?

ps 2: My output labels is a 60 element vector. So I could run a LinearRegression 60 times and then run 60 predictions to predict. But that seems like a hack

Comment: did you find a solution for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native implementation from what I've known but if you look at the scikit-learn implementation for [Multioutput regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-regression) it says that the "strategy consists of fitting one regressor per target. Since each target is represented by exactly one regressor it is possible to gain knowledge about the target by inspecting its corresponding regressor".

This means that a potential implementation could be to parallelize the regression step for each target. You could then distribute the calculation at the same time to speed things up.